When using [FromForm] line endings become \r\n - Can this be configured to only \n?
Our application consists of an angular frontend and a c# .net backend. We use textareas with characterlimits in the html file. Now to the problem:
In most places the text in the textarea is sent to the backend and written into the database without any problems, because for line-breaks only \n gets used which is interpreted as one character.
In two cases we use the annotation [FromForm] in our Controllers, because we get an additional file from the frontend. The line-endings of the string-properties in these dtos become \r\n which is interpreted as two characters.
If we write a text in the frontend with x characters and send it to the backend which has the annotation [MaxLength(x)] on the property, the first case (\n) is written into the database and the second case (\r\n) throws an error because the string is longer than it should be.
Is there a way to configure that all strings have the same line break(\n)? We don't want to use "hacks" by using string.replace or add some length to x.
Thanks for all the answers!
string.replace("\r\n","\n") 

works but is not a good solution
Tried debugging frontend and backend. Thats why we lnow, that the Problem is on the line breaks.
Expected: all strings have the same line ending, so that there are no unexpected values.
Update:
Frontend gets \n and sends it to the backend (via Swagger). Backend gets \r\n without us doing anything

Where did you see \r\n ? ASP.NET doesn't care what's contained in a POST body and browsers don't use \r\n. If the user pastes text with \r\n, it won't be modified by the browser, Angular or ASP.NET

we get an additional file from the frontend what does this mean? File fields (ie input type='file' aren't passed as text. Is the textarea used to pass file names to the server? Does it have the wrap attribute perhaps? That can generate \r\n for wrapping lines  when the form is submitted according to MDN. The default is soft

We use a dto with some other properties. one of them is IFormFile which requires [FromForm] annotation in the controller. One of the other properties is said string that causes the problem..
\r\n was seen when debugging in the backend.

There is no wrap attribute

Which means wrap='soft is enabled by default. Are those file names wrapped? In any case, this has nothing to do with ASP.NET. If the browser sends \r\n, the controller will receive \r\n. You can check what's sent in the Network tab of your browser's Developer tools. You may be able to avoid the problem by making the textarea a bit wider. Or you may have to clean up the contents before you submit the form

sounds like you're reading a file?  Windows will use \r\n for hard line break.  Mac/Linux use a single \n or \r.  What you are doing to conform all input seems correct, but might want to add a case for a single "\r" if supporting old Mac, pre-OSX files.

You can also conform to server environment's newline: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.newline?view=net-8.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN#System_Environment_NewLine

I did look some more into the values of the variables and updated the question accordingly

@browsermator I'm not reading a file but on this page one can upload a file. One of the form controls is a string where the user can write a text with up to 500 characters. These include line breaks.
When watching the frontend service, all the line breaks are sent as \n. But the backend gets \r\n and I don't understand why..
Also I'm sorry for phrasing things wrong - I'm still a student :')

this might actually vary by browser/platform.  The http standard for markup is for hard line break: CRLF, so \r\n.  All others are treated as whitespace... but standards aren't always followed.  If you need to conform frontend and backend validations, you might disregard all line breaks as they are non-printing characters.  If you want to handle on backend, you might use this convenience method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replacelineendings?view=net-8.0  For the standard see here: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3676.txt
